# how to get corresponding associated products images in magento

Tags: configurable-product, image

I want to display the simple product images associated with configurable products after click the option like color green.

I have referred the following link to show up
[reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QmRs.png)

But I did not get the associated product images.I'm using [pagayo theme][2]

1. I have selected **size1** as **XXL** and **color1** as **green**
   ![enter image description here][3]
   I'm getting the display like below:
   [image]
   But i did not get more images in more views.More views only displaying default configurable images.

Kindly help me to get it!!
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think about updating to 1.9.1 and use the built in color swatches, instead of hacking it yourself:

http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#catalog/product-configurable-swatch.html

I can't find the entry in the knowledge base of magento, which was a lot better than the link. Maybe this helps: http://sherodesigns.com/tutorial-configurable-swatches-in-magento/

But afaik you can't use the images from the simple products. If you need this, you can use the "Easylife Switcher" made by Marius. https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher

Comment: hi @Fabian Blechschmidt, i have edited my out come...kindly check it

Comment: I have accepted your answer.But why can't I get my preferred output by that reference link.I need to use with selecting the colors by the showed way

Comment: I think only the big image is implemented to be replaced. No clue how to do the rest.

Comment: @ Fabian Blechschmidt : okay...Thank you @ Fabian Blechschmidt:) I'm trying to achieve it...If I, will update the answer